# Is it possible to create a design of a web page using machine learning? Like generating CSS styles, assuming that we already had HTML

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

There are many machine learning algorithms to generate music, like Magenta and GRUV. I want to know if it is possible to create algorithms like these but for generating styles for webpages.

Comment: Yes. That is, it is possible. Why would it not be? As higher level design programs are evolved, they are converging on AI assist.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's totally possible. Andrej Karpathy wrote a blog post about Recurrent Neural Networks and shows several applications; one of them is generating Wikipedia articles including Markdown code, XML. The RNN could also generate LaTeX code which only needed slight corrections before being able to run, and also pieces of code in the style of Linux source code! [You can read the blog here](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/).